# Select2 weird dropdown positioning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I'm trying to add Select2 functionality to my dropdown list, however, the position of the Select2 list is totally messed up. See below
[image]

Code:

js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-Selector").select2({
        
        });
    });
```

html file:

```
<label for="input-time">Select local timezone: </label>

<p>
    <select class="js-Selector"></select>
</p>
```

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: $(".js-Selector").select2() ??? what is select2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the styles for the installation of the Select2 drop-down are missing. Make sure you have followed the [installation steps](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) and included a link to the stylesheet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```